# How to fix jeans where the belt loops have pulled out?

Tags: fabric

Just as the question asks: how do I fix my favorite pair of jeans where a couple of the belt loops have pulled away free from the jeans? They're still attached to the jeans by the top of the loop, but now there's a small hole where they've come detached at the bottom of the loop. I've been trying to be diligent about not using them to pull my pants up, but I might have done so without thinking.

I'd like to reattach them. I don't have access to a sewing machine or "spare" pieces of denim.

Comment: Hi Phil N DeBlanc welcome to lifehacks. We hope you enjoy your stay and sharing your knowledge and experience with us.

Comment: Are these jeans the only ones you have with pulled loops? Do you use the belt loops in your jeans for a belt?

Comment: No, @Stan, one the first question. Yes on the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any suitable cloth as a backing (used under the surface) for the jeans. A small square of any stiff fabric would be useable.

A hack would be to use an Iron-on patch inside your jeans. If you don't want to do that, you can find fabric glue.

After the hole is plugged, hand sew the bottom of the loop back on to cover the "hole" the same as the rest of the loops are attached.

[image: Belt loop repair suggestion]

Normally, this is a bar stitch or an 'X'.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Take them to a tailor and have them professionally repaired.  Many dry cleaning establishments have a tailor on staff.

Sometimes a lifehack is not the best or even the cheapest solution.